# How to get technical details, description, stars and price through Amazon API?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api

I have worked before with the AWS API. You can get quite info about products. But now I need specifically to gather: technical details, description, stars and price.

I am using basically this request URL (more other variables as Timestamp and Signature):

```
$request = $this->AMAZON_URL . "?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=" . $this->KEYID;
$request .= "&AssociateTag=" . $this->ASSOCTAG . "&Version=" . $this->VERSION . "&Operation=ItemLookup";
$request .= "&ItemId=$asin&ResponseGroup=Medium,Offers";
```

As you must know we receive a bunch of data but seems quite difficult specifically ask for only some specifics ones. for instance: technical details, description, stars and price.

Currently I obtain data mostly through parsing the following node:

```
{ parsed xml variable }->Items->Item->ItemAttributes
```

Comment: did you get the solution for technical details ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codediesel.com/php/accessing-amazon-product-advertising-api-in-php/

This link will answer all your questions. In the comments are detailed how to on getting reviews and more, as well as a link to amazons API reference on their site.

Enjoy.

EDITED: SOME ANSWERS BELOW

Upon further research it appears it is impossible. Even certain items that have technical details it seems it only passes key ones on. Such as DisplaySize and a few others but in most cases no technical details are available. It seems that most cases refer to cameras as having small amounts of tech data passed on but never what is needed. Tho I did find FormattedPrice Ancestry: OfferSummary/LowestUsedPrice/FormattedPrice OfferSummary/LowestCollectiblePrice/FormattedPrice OfferSummary/LowestNewPrice/FormattedPrice Which I hope helps with the price bit.

Also found out stars was removed November 8th n no longer can be accessed through the API at all. Also description as quoted "EditorialReview part of the response contains the product description."

Comment: I have seen that page too. Can you specifically answer my question? Have you used AWS sometime? THX.-

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I have never worked with amazon and am at work at the moment. Like I said though if you read in the comments, there is a man requesting code for pulling reviews from amazon. The same will apply for what you are asking and the specific names to call will be supplied in the link to amazon below the code in the comments.

Comment: Well, I have worked with Amazon before and my question is very specific (and is for experienced coders in the `tags` of the question). This question is not easy to respond, that's why I asked here in SO. If you don't know an answer please do not answer (just redound in a lost of time). All of us can surf the Internet too and I already saw the page you recommend, so try to not respond with links. Besides I ask for `technical details, description, stars and price.` NOT reviews! (and you are wrong if you think that is enough change `reviews` with `description`, etc) THX anyway.

Comment: Well I'm sorry I didn't do all your coding for you. Feel free to read and adapt the comment code as stated before to retrieve the necessary information. And as stated the proper things to search for will be located in the amazon API reference.

Comment: I did not ask you resolve any problem (All of us in SO can freely ask and respond to other members). I just tell you: TRY **do not respond when you do not know something**...

Comment: Upon further research it appears it is impossible. Even certain items that have technical details it seems it only passes key ones on. Such as DisplaySize and a few others but in most cases no technical details are available. It seems that most cases refer to cameras as having small amounts of tech data passed on but never what is needed. Tho I did find FormattedPrice

Ancestry: 
OfferSummary/LowestUsedPrice/FormattedPrice
OfferSummary/LowestCollectiblePrice/FormattedPrice
OfferSummary/LowestNewPrice/FormattedPrice
Which I hope helps with the price bit.

Comment: Also found out stars was removed November 8th n no longer can be accessed through the API at all. Also description as quoted "EditorialReview part of the response contains the product description."

Comment: @HenryGuy your comments could be useful to others and you really should edit your question and add your findings there.

Comment: @HenryGuy another tip: if you are responding to a users comment use the @<User> tag. This way the comment will show up in the users home page. I just happened to check back here and saw your response.

Comment: @Jonathan Spooner gotcha. I'm on an iPhone and I help people out while I'm slow at work. Apparently there is a nifty toolbar for replies but since I'm on a mobile phone I don't see it.